# how to get objects from array by value inside desired object by mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, non-relational-database

I have following bson data in mongoDB

```
{
 name : "company 1",
 createPurchaseOrder :[
  {
     partyName : "p1",
     poNumber : "789",
  },
  {
     partyName : "p2",
     poNumber : "700",
  },
  {
     partyName : "p3",
     poNumber : "889",
  },
 {
     partyName : "p1",
     poNumber : "800",
  },
 {
     partyName : "p1",
     poNumber : "200",
  },
 ]
}
```

I want objects from partyName for example if partyName is p1 then I want this

```
[
    {
        partyName: 'p1',
        poNumber: '789',
    },
    {
        partyName: 'p1',
        poNumber: '800',
    },
    {
        partyName: 'p1',
        poNumber: '200',
    },
];
```

I tried this

```
const user1 = await User.findOne({name : "company 1"},{createPurchaseOrder:{$elemMatch:{partyName:"p1"}}})
```

its gives me only first matched object, then I tried this

```
const user1 = await User.find({name : "company 1"},{createPurchaseOrder:{$elemMatch:{"partyName.$":"p1"}}})
```

it returned an empty array. please help me with this I want solution which gives me all objects which have matched value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the aggregation pipeline for this, the `find` operator is very limited with what structure transformation it can do and for example this use case can't be achieved using it.

Just use `$filter` instead:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      name: "company 1"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      createPurchaseOrder: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $ifNull: [
              "$createPurchaseOrder",
              []
            ]
          },
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.partyName",
              "p1"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$createPurchaseOrder"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$createPurchaseOrder"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qylFUmZSwfq)

Comment: i tried this but its not working. it gives entire bson data of company 1

Comment: Just add an `$unwind` stage, like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qylFUmZSwfq)